# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace' with backbone.js and coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend(
  defaults: 
    name: 'Jony James'
    age: 30
    occupation:  'developer'

  validate: (attrs) ->
    if attrs.age < 0
      return 'Age must be positive, stupid.'
    if not attrs.name
      return 'A person must have a name! fool.'

  work: ->
    @get('name') + " is working." 
    )

PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li'

    #template: _.template($('#personTemplate').html())
    template: "#personTemplate"

    initialize: ->
      @render()

    render: ->
      template = _.template($(@template))
      @$el.html(template)

    })

person = new Person
personView = new PersonView( model: person)
$(document.body).append personView.el
```

On my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
   <strong><%= name %></strong> (<%= age %>) - <%= occupation %> 
  </script>
  <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

With `template: _.template($('#personTemplate').html())` and `@$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))` is working fine.

but with current version of `main.js` I get this error in google chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'
```

**Where is the error?**

Thank you!

Comment: I'm familiar with Backbone, but not with coffeescript so excuse me if I'm reading it incorrectly, but it looks as if you're not actually passing in the model/variables into the template when you are rendering it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the template function.  Try passing the html instead of a jQuery object:

`template = _.template($(@template).html(), @model.toJSON())`

Comment: It is not working with .html. `I get Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined`.

Comment: Thank you is correct. I have replaced `this.model` by `@model`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot it was coffeescript.